# angularJS show validation of the message

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation

```js
here is the angular code. 

.controller("myStuList", ['$scope', "weejoinMessage", "httpServer", "$modal", "ngWeeJoinServer", "stuServer", function ($scope, weejoinMessage, httpServer, $modal, server, stuServer) {
    
        //第一次进入是加载所有学员数据
        $scope.stuinfos = infos.info; // i give the data form info.info to stuinfos.

        //
        $scope.course = '';
        $scope.class = '';
        $scope.name = '';
        $scope.age = '';
        $scope.scores = '';

        $scope.createNew = function () {
            httpServer.httpHandle({
                url: stuBag.action.createNew,
                data: {
                    courseId: $scope.course,
                    classId:$scope.class,
                    stuname: $scope.name,
                    age: $scope.age,
                    scores: $scope.scores
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    weejoinMessage.messageSuccess("添加成功！");                   
                    $scope.stuinfos.push({ 'CourseName': $scope.course, 'ClassName': $scope.class, 'StuName': $scope.name, 'Age': $scope.age, 'Scores': $scope.scores });                   
                }
            });
           
        };
```

please help to see the problem. all the validation message show up togather when open the create page.
look down the html code .i want to show the validation message when click on the input text. and when the input message is wrong according to the validation . and show the message below the input texbox.

```html
<div ng-app="stu.info" ng-controller="myStuList">
    <form name="createnew_form"  class="form-horizontal" role="form" ng-submit="createNew()" novalidate>


        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="stuname" class="col-md-2 control-label">姓名</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="姓名" name="stuname" ng-model="name" ng-minlength=3 ng-maxlength=20 required />
                <div class="error" ng-show="createnew_form.stuname.$dirty && createnew_form.stuname.$invalid">
                    <small class="error" ng-show="createnew_form.stuname.$error.required">
                        请输入姓名
                    </small>
                    <small class="error" ng-show="createnew_form.stuname.$error.minlength">
                        至少输入两个字
                    </small>
                    <small class="error" ng-show="createnew_form.stuname.$error.maxlength">
                        最多输入五个字
                    </small>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label">年龄</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="number" min="0" max="100" required class="form-control" name="age"
                       ng-model="age" />
                <div class="error-container" ng-show="createnew_form.age.$dirty && createnew_form.age.$invalid">                    
                    <small class="error" ng-show="createnew_form.age.$error.required">
                        请输入年龄
                    </small>
                    <small class="error" ng-show="createnew_form.age.$error.min">
                        最小年龄为0
                    </small>
                    <small class="error" ng-show="createnew_form.age.$error.max">
                        最大年龄为100
                    </small>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-group">
            <div style="padding-left:110px">
                <input type="submit" value="确认添加" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: any console errors ?

Comment: please check the angularjs code.and help me find the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used your code on jsFiddle and the form validation is working as expected. 
I'm not seeing all the error messages together as you've mentioned. Please see the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/giri_jeedigunta/4508cd4r/

Your HTML Code:

```html
<div ng-app="stu.info" ng-controller="myStuList">
    <form name="createnew_form"  class="form-horizontal" role="form" ng-submit="createNew()" novalidate>


        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="stuname" class="col-md-2 control-label">姓名</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="姓名" name="stuname" ng-model="name" ng-minlength=3 ng-maxlength=20 required />
                <div class="error" ng-show="createnew_form.stuname.$dirty && createnew_form.stuname.$invalid">
                    <small class="error" ng-show="createnew_form.stuname.$error.required">
                        请输入姓名
                    </small>
                    <small class="error" ng-show="createnew_form.stuname.$error.minlength">
                        至少输入两个字
                    </small>
                    <small class="error" ng-show="createnew_form.stuname.$error.maxlength">
                        最多输入五个字
                    </small>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label">年龄</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="number" min="0" max="100" required class="form-control" name="age"
                       ng-model="age" />
                <div class="error-container" ng-show="createnew_form.age.$dirty && createnew_form.age.$invalid">                    
                    <small class="error" ng-show="createnew_form.age.$error.required">
                        请输入年龄
                    </small>
                    <small class="error" ng-show="createnew_form.age.$error.min">
                        最小年龄为0
                    </small>
                    <small class="error" ng-show="createnew_form.age.$error.max">
                        最大年龄为100
                    </small>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-group">
            <div style="padding-left:110px">
                <input type="submit" value="确认添加" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't `creatnew_form.course.$invalid` be `createnew_form.course.$invalid` (with an 'e' in "createnew")?

Comment: yes. but when i changed this. it will show all the error message together on the view page